# Why is this JavaScript constructor generated by Typescript wrapped an immediately-invoked function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Could someone explain to me what is the advantage of this 'constructor' definition:

```
var Tree = (function () {
  function Tree(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  return Tree;
})();
```

instead of

```
var Tree = function(name) {
   this.name = name;
};
```

The first variant is produced by the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Those two are absolutely equivalent, at least the way you have them here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TypeScript's case, there extra closure is also there for capturing the base class

```
class Animal {
    public run() {
        console.log('running!');
    }
}

class Giraffe extends Animal {
    public run() {
        super.run();
        console.log('... and looking awkward');
    }
}
```

Emits:

```
var Animal = (function () {
    function Animal() {
    }
    Animal.prototype.run = function () {
        console.log('running!');
    };
    return Animal;
})();

var Giraffe = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Giraffe, _super);
    function Giraffe() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Giraffe.prototype.run = function () {
        _super.prototype.run.call(this);
        console.log('... and looking awkward');
    };
    return Giraffe;
})(Animal);
```

Note the use of `_super.prototype` to refer to the base class via the parameter (`Animal` here) passed to the immediately-invoked function. Without the extra closure, there'd be nowhere to save that value without polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 5):

In this specific example, there are no differences.
There may be differences if you want to retain in scope some variables:

```
var Tree = (function () {
  var greeting = "Hello ";
  function Tree(name) {
    this.firstname = greeting + name;
  }
  return Tree;
})();
```

Also, in this case there is no way to modify the `greeting` variable (in fact, it's private).

Comment: Definition for [property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.26) and [variable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2). Please don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 2):

The function will be named, which will produce more useful results in stacktraces and debugging tools.

However, you could achieve the same effect with:

```
function Tree(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

If you have simplified the code, then you might have removed the use of a closure that might have created something akin to a Class variable (a piece of data shared between all instances of a function).

Comment: But in the most examples (e.g Mozilla), function (constructor) is assigned to the variable.